# "Which" versus "that" when I can't put off the phrase by comma

Tags: relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

> John takes a long sling, connects its one end to **the cam** which is inserted into the hole close by her and connects the other end to the climbing rope.

There are many cams. "The cam" refers to a particular cam. I think I should use *which* but some [grammar references](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/which-versus-that.aspx) says I have put a comma before *which*. I don't think it's correct to put a comma before *which*.

Should I use *that* or *which*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is involved here is the distinction between *restrictive* and *non-restrictive* relative clauses.

A *restrictive* relative clause is called that because the clause *restricts* the scope of what is said about the noun or noun phrase it modifies. It specifies *which* noun is meant.

In your case, if *which is inserted into the hole close by her* is a *restrictive* clause it means that John connects the sling to a cam in that position and no other.

If it is a *non-restrictive* clause, then the position of the cam is irrelevant. It is just by happenstance that the cam is there.

The role of the comma is to distinguish these two sorts of clause: a non-restrictive clause is set off by a comma (or two, if it falls in the middle of the sentence), a restrictive clause is not.

> RESTRICTIVE: John takes a long sling, connects its one end to the cam which is inserted into the hole close by her and connects the other end to the climbing rope.
>
> NON-RESTRICTIVE: John takes a long sling, connects its one end to the cam, which is inserted into the hole close by her, and connects the other end to the climbing rope.

NOTE: I myself would put a comma **after** *by her* in both sentences, to make the structure clearer; but that is not required, and here it might confuse you, so I have left it out.

There is one other clue to whether the clause is restrictive or non-restrictive: if the relative pronoun which introduces the clause is *that*, the clause **must** be restrictive. The relative pronoun *that* cannot be used at the start of a non-restrictive clause. *Who* or *which*, however, can be used with either sort of clause.

For about the first sixty years of the 20th century it was fashionable among some "authorities" to require *that* at the start of all restrictive relative clauses; but that "rule" was never widely followed and is now disappearing just as fast as it arrived. Grammar Girl is one of those who maintains it. But if you are taking a class in English, do as your teacher tells you -- until you have passed all the exams!

NOTE: [**Here**](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/tw-a-pragmatic-approach/) I give my reasons for almost never using *that* as a relative pronoun; but you are no more bound by my practise than by Grammar Girl's.

Comment: As ever, it helps to remember English is primarily *spoken*. The "non-restrictive" sense is normally distinguished in speech by a *pause* (comma in the pallid imitation *written* form). Given that unambiguous mechanism, it's pretty much irrelevant whether you use *that* or a *wh-form*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, in improvised speech (as opposed to read or practised speech), pauses are not diagnostic because a pause may fall at any point the speaker needs to slow down and formulate what they're going to say next. (And an intentional, calculated 'pause' is rarely an actual pause, it's just a lengthening and a falling tone on the previous vowel, with gemination of the terminal consonant.)

Comment: Sure, but as John L pointed out elsewhere, "pause" is a pretty inaccurate term, since what we *perceive* as pauses (doubtless much influenced by written forms) are mainly fluxions of intonation & stress. Which we're all *really* good at picking up on, even if English isn't formally classified as a "tonal" language.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I chose a post where my question is somewhat related. Could you please answer this query of mine? Is the following affirmation always true, or is it a generalisation? `...the purpose of a defining relative clause is to introduce and identify someone or something that has not yet appeared in the narrative.`

Comment: @Mari-LouA  If I understand your question correctly, it's not even *usually* true. A relative clause **can** be used that way, but it is also used to restrict the reference of its head to an individual or subset of a previously identified group (e.g. "Here are six pennies; let's look more closely at the two **which were minted before 2008**").

Comment: Thank you so much, and thank you for the brilliant example too. It's very clear. I suspected it was a generalization, but hearing it is not even usually true, was a surprise to say the least.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Coming up with a better definition of the restrictive/non-restrictive contrast--and of modifier/predication contrasts in general--has occupied me a lot lately. My latest thought is that a modifier supplies either *old assertions* or *presuppositions* about the head, while predications supply *new assertions* about the head.